# What are possible sanctions the U.S. could put against North Korea if they were to provide arms to Russia?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, sanctions, north-korea

> Foreign governments and experts have speculated that Kim will likely
> supply ammunition to Russia in exchange for receiving advanced weapons
> or technology from Russia.
>
> Milley and the other defense chiefs from NATO countries are meeting at
> the Holmenkollen ski area on the edge of Oslo over the next several
> days to discuss support for Ukraine and other regional defense issues.
> From there, Milley will attend the monthly meeting of the Ukraine
> Defense Contact Group in Germany on Tuesday. That group, led by U.S.
> Defense Secretary Lloyd Austin, is the main international forum for
> drumming up military support for Ukraine.

From [North Korean arms for Russia probably wouldn't make a big difference in the Ukraine war, Milley says](https://nationalpost.com/pmn/news-pmn/north-korean-arms-for-russia-probably-wouldnt-make-a-big-difference-in-the-ukraine-war-milley-says)

What are possible sanctions the U.S. could put against North Korea if they were to provide arms to Russia? There are a lot of sanctions that were enacted against North Korea already, does the U.S. have enough room for more sanctions against North Korea that could make them think twice before providing arms to Russia?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The US could always enact more **secondary sanctions** against people who trade with the DPRK. Since Russia and China are high on the list of North Korea's trading partners, there are practical limits to this, but there are a few others left.

Comment: More Sanctions on Russia for being a DPRK trade partner doesn't seem that reaslistic. Any sanctions anyone would put on Russia would be put on them for Ukraine and not as secondary sanctions

Comment: @Hobbamok, an astonishing amount of trade with Russia is *not yet* sanctioned.

Comment: while that is true, if that trade is further sanctioned, I heavily doubt that trade with North Korea will be the deciding/significant factor in levying them. I didn't really know how to word that though